# Debugging shared embedded (?) views in MVC3/4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I did some research about this but had no luck finding any solution.

This is a two-aspect problem:

1. Sharing views between multiple projects. This is easily done by i.e. embedding them in a common project and providing by virtual path provider.
   The problem is that they can't be stepped into by a VS debugger, since it has no way of correlating physical cshtml files with these JITted.
2. Debugging common views. This is the part where I stuck in. I have no idea how to do this.

What I have done:
I created a project with common views (with a "content" type, not emvedded) and a symbolic link in every project, which leads to the appropriate folder. I also added this path to a RazorViewEngine in application_start. 
This works fine, I even get a line number when there's an exception thrown in a view, except that VS debugger still can't step into this view :/

In order to debug views one have to have them in a project, but it can't really be done - we obviously use TFS, so they would be multiplied in tfs.

To make the story short: **is there any way to step into a shared view while debugging in VS2010?**

This is quite a major problem for us, any ideas are appreciated